# awk FS vs FPAT puzzle and counting words but not blank fields

Tags: bash, awk

Suppose I have the file:

```
$ cat file
This, that;
this-that or this.
```

(Punctuation at the line end is not always there...)

Now I want to count *words* (with words being defined as one or more ascii case-insensitive letters.) In typical POSIX *nix you could do:

```
sed -nE 's/[^[:alpha:]]+/ /g; s/ $//p' file | tr ' ' "\n"  | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq -c
   1 or
   2 that
   3 this
```

With grep you can shorten that a bit to only match what you define as a word:

```
grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]+' file | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq -c
# same output
```

With GNU awk, you can use `FPAT` to replicate matching only what you want (ignore sorting...):

```
gawk -v FPAT="[[:alpha:]]+" '
{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {seen[tolower($i)]++}}
END {for (e in seen) printf "%4s %s\n", seen[e], e}' file
   3 this
   1 or
   2 that
```

Now trying to replicate in POSIX `awk` I tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[^[:alpha:]]+"}
{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) seen[tolower($i)]++ }
END {for (e in seen) printf "%4s %s\n", seen[e], e}' file
   2 
   3 this
   1 or
   2 that
```

Note the `2` with blank at top. This is from having blank fields from `;` at the end of line 1 and `.` at the end of line 2. If you delete the punctuation at line's end, this issue goes away.

You can partially fix it (for all but the last line) by setting `RS=""` in the awk, but still get a blank field with the last (only) line.

I can also fix it this way:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[^[:alpha:]]+"}
{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i) seen[tolower($i)]++ }
END {for (e in seen) printf "%4s %s\n", seen[e], e}' file
```

Which seems a little less than straight forward.

Is there an idiomatic fix I am missing to make POSIX awk act similarly to GNU awk's FPAT solution here?

Comment: You don't need `-P` for that pattern, there's nothing pcre-specific about it: `-E` will do.

Comment: NOTE: Not all lines would have non-letters at the end so that blank field will not ALWAYS be there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work in POSIX/BSD or any version of `awk`:

```sh
awk -F '[^[:alpha:]]+' '
{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) ($i != "") && ++count[tolower($i)]}
END {for (e in count) printf "%4s %s\n", count[e], e}' file

   1 or
   3 this
   2 that
```

- By using `-F '[^[:alpha:]]+'` we are splitting fields on any non-alpha character.
- `($i != "")` condition will make sure to count only non-empty fields in `seen`.

Comment: If you remove the punctuation at the end of the lines in the example now that legitimate word is no longer included in the word count. Removing `;` and `.` from the example decreases `this` to 2 and `that` to 1.

Comment: Ah that's good point. Answer is updated to address this

Comment: Now similar to the solution I already had of `{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i) seen[tolower($i)]++ }` which is the heart of the question: Is that optimal cross `g?awk` solution?

Comment: Indeed it is very similar (sorry I lost track in multiple code samples). 
I think this is fairly optimal solution that would work across all awk versions.

Comment: And I return to a variant that triggered the question in the first place...

Answer (score 3):

With POSIX awk, I'd use `match` and the builtin RSTART and RLENGTH variables:

```
#!awk
{
    s = $0
    while (match(s, /[[:alpha:]]+/)) {
        word = substr(s, RSTART, RLENGTH)
        count[tolower(word)]++
        s = substr(s, RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
END {
    for (word in count) print count[word], word
}
```

```
$ awk -f countwords.awk file
1 or
3 this
2 that
```

Works with the default BSD awk on my Mac.

Answer (score 3):

Using `RS` instead:

```
$ gawk -v RS="[^[:alpha:]]+" '  # [^a-zA-Z] or something for some awks
$0 {                            # remove possible leading null string
    a[tolower($0)]++
}
END {
    for(i in a)
        print i,a[i]
}' file
```

Output:

```
this 3
or 1
that 2
```

Tested successfully on gawk and Mac awk (version 20200816) and on mawk and busybox awk using `[^a-zA-Z]`

Comment: This is a very good g?awk solution.

Comment: Just a note that POSIX awk doesn't support multi character `RS`.  Just run this with `gawk --posix ...` to see very different behavior.

Comment: *Just a note that POSIX awk doesn't support multi character* Hmmmm. It **does** work on Mac default `awk` but then [the docs say](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/awk.html) **If RS contains more than one character, the results are unspecified.** and running `gawk` with `--posix` does indeed break this...

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk` in case you are ok to do this with `RS` approach.

```
awk -v RS='[[:alpha:]]+' '
RT{
  val[tolower(RT)]++
}
END{
  for(word in val){
    print val[word], word
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `RS` variable of `awk` to make record separator as `[[:alpha:]]` then in main program creating array val whose index is RT variable and keep counting its occurrences with respect to same index in array val. In `END` block of this program traversing through array and printing indexes with its respective values.

Comment: Creative! However, the `RT` variable is GNU awk only though, no? I would use FPAT if I knew it was GNU.

Comment: @dawg, Thank you for encouraging. Honestly I don't have posix `awk` with me so I couldn't test in it, that's why I mentioned written and tested in GNU `awk`, if you have that would like to request to test this once and we both could learn it will work or not :) cheers.

Comment: It does not work on POSIX awk but does work on gawk on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk` using `patsplit()` and a second array for counting, you can try this:

```
awk 'patsplit($0, a, /[[:alpha:]]+/) {for (i in a) b[ tolower(a[i]) ]++} END {for (j in b) print b[j], j}' file
3 this
1 or
2 that
```

Comment: Thanks! But really looking for a NON GNU solution since the FPAT solution works great. Looking for a completely POSIX / GNU neutral solution.